# I can't see members in group in Process Admin

Tags: websphere, ibm-bpm

I have problem in IBM BPM. I don't see members in group in Process Admin (**ProcessAdmin -> User Managment -> Group Management**) 
I click in group and I don't see any members. Groups exist and connecting between user-group exist in database, Websphere, AD.
I call rest api -> **IBM Business Automation Workflow REST APIs -> Organization API -> Group Details** and value of returning member is NULL (but it isn't true).
When I call user in rest api **IBM Business Automation Workflow REST APIs -> Organization API -> User Details** the group name is returning (is correct). Problem is when I call group because don't return any members. When I call user I see groups. 
***How I tried to fix it:***

- restart IBM BPM (BPM + DMG)
- synchronize users, group by script like in documentation https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFTN5_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.admin.doc/topics/sync_users_and_groups.html
- delete connect with AD and connect again

Do you have any ideas, why can't I see a member in groups?

Comment: What version of WebSphere?

Comment: version of WebSphare is 8.5.5.15

Comment: The Active Directory LDAP config is in [profile_directory]/config/cells/[cell_name]/wim/config/wimconfig.xml. I would verify the information is accurate, specifically group and member properties. For example, how is group membership defined in your AD server? The default for Websphere is member or memberof, so if you want uniqueMember, eg., this would need to be specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. I had incorrect value in:

Global security -> Federated repositories -> Manage repositories -> AD -> Federates repositories property names to LDAP attributes mapping -> samAccountName
and incorrect value in "Property name"